# Bootstrap V5 LTR and RTL in Laravel 8

Tags: css, sass, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use the **[Bootstrap V5 LTR and RTL at the same time](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/)** in my **laravel 8 application** when I switch to **Arabic language (RTL) mode** the design look terrible. I don't know why because I followed all the instructions **[mentioned there](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/)**...

**Here is my Codes :**

**resources/sass/app.scss**

```
/* rtl:begin:options: {
  "autoRename": true,
  "stringMap":[
    "name": "ltr-rtl",
    "priority": 100,
    "search": ["ltr"],
    "replace": ["rtl"],
    "options": {
      "scope": "*",
      "ignoreCase": false
    }
  ]
} */
.ltr {
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
}
/*rtl:end:options*/
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

**resources/views/example.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" dir="{{ (app()->isLocale('ar') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr') }}" class="ltr">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have same issue